# How to stop 'az login' from changing my default subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I tried to access specific subscription in my organization by using command:

```
az login --subscription ID
```

It works and `az account list` gives me info that I changed this sub to default:

```
{
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "ID",
    "id": "ID",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Development and Test",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "ID",
    "user": {
      "name": "pawel@organization.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
```

but after using `az login` it logs me back to different subscription on this account:

```
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "ID",
    "id": "ID",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Visual Studio Professional Subscription",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "ID",
    "user": {
      "name": "pawel@organization.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
```

Both are on the same account. How can I force to login on the first subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell 7** was causing this issue, after many retrys, colleague asked me to try **Windows PowerShell** (old version) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell command to mark a particular subscription as default from [remote PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-6.0.0)

```
 Set-AzContext
   [-Context] <PSAzureContext>
   [-ExtendedProperty <System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]>]
   [-Name <String>]
   [-Force]
   [-Scope <ContextModificationScope>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: @Paweł Chojnacki - If the above provided answer is helpful ? If so could you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.